# Adding a second submit handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to modify an existing web page which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="s1.js"></script>
```

s1.js has something like this:

```
window.onDomReady = DomReady;

function DomReady(fn)
{
    if(document.addEventListener)
    {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn, false);
    }
    else
    {
        document.onreadystatechange = function(){chState(fn);};
    }
}

function chState(fn)
{
    if(document.readyState == "interactive" || document.readyState == "complete")
        fn();
}


window.onDomReady(addHndlrs);

function addHndlrs()
{
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) 
    {
        var form = forms[i];
        if(form.addEventListener)
        {
            form.addEventListener("submit", DoValidate, false);
        }
        else if (form.attachEvent)
        {
            form.attachEvent("onsubmit", DoValidate);
        } 
    
        Other stuff.
    
    }
```

When I click Submit on the form, `DoValidate` does get called.

I am trying to modify this page to add another submit handler which is called after the first one.

I copied the above code, changed function names and put into s2.js:

```
window.onDomReady = DReady;

function DReady(fn)
{
    if(document.addEventListener)
    {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn, false);
    }
    else
    {
        document.onreadystatechange = function(){Chk1State(fn);};
    }
}

function Chk1State(fn)
{
    if(document.readyState == "interactive" || document.readyState == "complete")
        fn();
}

window.onDomReady(myready);

function myready()
{
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) 
    {
        var form = forms[i];
        if(form.addEventListener) 
        {
            form.addEventListener("submit", mynewhandler, false);
        }
        else if (form.attachEvent) 
        {
            form.attachEvent("onsubmit", mynewhandler);
        }
    }

}
```

In the form html, I added a reference to it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="s1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="s2.js"></script>
```

My new submit handler never gets called. I debugged it through Firebug - I see `DReady` being called and my DOM Ready handler being registered. However `myready` never gets called, so my submit handler never gets registered.

What am I missing here? I tried changing order of inclusion of s1.js and s2.js but that doesn't seem to help. I want to do this without modifying s1.js

Comment: Just add a call to your function in the end of "DoValidate" function.

Comment: @JoelDuret  No - I want to do this without modifying s1.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you provided seems to be fine! Have checked in Chrome 25, FireFox 19 and IE 10!

Normally I find it easier to just modify the code at runtime (not the source file), thanks to JavaScript being dynamic typed, you could overwrite the `DoValidate` function with your own, passing it the original `DoValidate` through closure in the `s2.js`:

```
var originalValidate = DoValidate;
DoValidate = function () {
    originalValidate();
    alert("my handler");
};
```

Comment: Worked. Great. Not a regular javascript programmer - I didn't even know one can overwrite a function this way. Much easier than all the stuff I was trying.